# How to freely use pojo's, having setters, as state in React

Tags: reactjs

Hitting a roadbump, I’m seeking some help.  I'm starting to move more of my "state" pojo's out of my React components, due to for example being unsure how how my pojo’s setter methods should be utilized now (one may want setter methods to validate, etc.).  I now find myself either defying React docs' warning to NEVER touch this.state directly or moving most code except rendering – including state - outside of the React component into my own js variables/objects (and holding a reference to the rendered object then using forceUpdate() to rerender).  What is the recommended way to freely use whatever plain old js data/model objects I want, including with setter methods?

This barebones example, where I’m wanting a form-backing data object, demonstrates this difference I’m facing: http://jsfiddle.net/jL0rf0ed/ vs. http://jsfiddle.net/rzuswg9x/.  Also pasted the code for the first below.

At the very least, I have this specific question: following a custom/manual update of this.state, does a this.setState(this.state) line, which would be from within the React component, and a component.forceUpdate() line, which would likely be from outside the React component, work just as fast and correctly as the standard this.setState({someKey: someValue})?

Thanks.

```
//props: dataObj, handleInputChange
test.ComponentA = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            age: 21,
            email: 'a@b.com', //TODO make members private
            setEmail: function(val) { //TODO utilize this
                this.email = val;
                if(val.indexOf('@') == -1) {
                    //TODO set or report an error
                }
            }
        }       
    },
    handleInputChange: function(e) {
        this.state[e.target.name]=e.target.value; //defying the "NEVER touch this.state" warning (but it appears to work fine)!
        this.setState(this.state); //and then this strange line
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input type='text' name='age' onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.age}></input>
                <input type='text' name='email' onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.email}></input>
                <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<test.ComponentA />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

For your code example in your pasted snippet, you can do the following.

```
handleInputChange: function(e) {
  var updates = {};
  updates[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  this.setState(updates);
},
```

In your second example, you should never call `forceUpdate` or `setState` from outside the component itself. The correct way would be for the state to be contained in whatever renders your component and pass in the data as props.

Usually this means you have a wrapper component.

```
var RootComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: ...

  onInputChange: function() {
    this.setState({yourKey: yourValue});
  },

  render: function() {
    return <SubComponent yourKey={this.state.yourKey} onInputChange={this.onInputChange} />;
  }
};
```

In your case, I would recommend creating this wrapper component. Another solution is just to rerender the same component into the same DOM node.

```
test.handleInputChange = function(e) {
  // update test.formPojo1 here
  React.render(<test.ComponentA dataObj={test.formPojo1} handleInputChange={...} />);
}
```

Because it is the same component class and DOM node, React will treat it as an update.

Answer (score 0):

### Stores

Facebook uses the concept of a [Store](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#creating-stores) in their [Flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/) architecture.

Stores are a very targeted POJO. And I find that it is pretty simple to use the Store metaphors without the using the entirety of Flux.

### Sample Store

This is a Store that I pulled out of one of our production React apps:

```
ChatMessageStore = {
  chatMessages: [],

  callbacks: [],

  getAll: function() {
    return this.chatMessages;
  },

  init: function() {
    this.chatMessages = window.chat_messages.slice();
    return this.emitChange();
  },

  create: function(message) {
    this.chatMessages.push(message);
    return this.emitChange();
  },

  emitChange: function() {
    return this.callbacks.forEach(callback, function() {
      return callback();
    });
  },

  addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    return this.callbacks.push(callback);
  },

  removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
    return this.callbacks = _.without(this.callbacks, callback);
  }
};
```

### Hooking it up to a React Component

In your component you can now query the store for its data:

```
var Chat = React.createClass({
  componentWillMount: function() {
    return ChatMessageStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    return ChatMessageStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return this.getMessageState();
  },

  getMessageState: function() {
    return {
      messages: ChatMessageStore.getAll()
    };
  }
});
```

The Component registers a callback with the Store, which is fired on every change, updating the component and obeying the law of "don't modify state."

Comment: answering react questions with flux is as bad as answering javascript questions with jquery.  granted it's a stackoverflow tradition; still, don't do it.

Comment: @JohnHaugeland I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume that you didn't read the question or the answer before posting this comment. Granted, it's a stackoverflow tradition. This answer is saying how to subscribe to a persisted object WITHOUT flux, allowing the OP to not use `forceUpdate`—which he would like to avoid.

Comment: Your benefit of the doubt is unnecessary.  This is a react question, and the leading sentence explains the flux worldview, which is significantly different than the react worldview.  I stand by my comment.